Webpack Getting Variables
    {% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Django Webpack template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    
    <p id="message">Template Data</p>

    <script id="templateDataScript" type="application/json">
      {{ template_data|safe }}
    </script>
    <script src="{% static 'data.bundle.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>

This seems to work file when I run it locally...
However, if I Webpack this and use my bundle file online it does not recognize the Django template_data. Trying to find out is it possible to somehow incorporate my variables and data into the Webpack itself.
Just searching for any insight.

You can make webpack work with Django with some configuration.  You can try using https://github.com/django-webpack/django-webpack-loader to make it easier.
